# Mover arquivos para uma determinada pasta automaticamente

Tags: script, batch, automatização

Tenho uma rotina de backup no SQL que gera automaticamente backup das bases de dados nesta pasta: `D:\Backup\Backup_SQL\Databases`

Criei um bat (forfiles) que compacta esses arquivos de backup e transfere para outra pasta. O script está rodando corretamente. Agora eu quero alterar a pasta de destino dos arquivos compactados porém esta pasta contém espaço em seu nome: Box Files. Esta pasta é de um aplicativo que joga o conteúdo dela própria na nuvem. Como a pasta contem espaço no nome, está dando erro na execução do script. É possível fazer com que o bat reconheça esta pasta com espaço?

Obs. Não é possível alterar o nome desta pasta pois é padrão do aplicativo Box.

Script bat utilizado:

```
REM Path to WinRAR executable in Program Files
 set path="C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\";%path%

set data=%DATE%
 set CURRDATE=%DATE:/=-%
 set dia=%data:~-0,4%

set horario=%time%
 set CURRTIME=%time:/=-%
 set hora=%horario:~-0,2%

rar a F:\Teste Teste\Databases_%CURRDATE%_%HORA%.rar D:\Backup\Backup_SQL\Databases

pause

@ECHO ON

-------

Resultado da execução do bat:


 D:\Backup\Script de backup>REM Path to WinRAR executable in Program Files

D:\Backup\Script de backup>set path="C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\";C:\Windows\
 system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShe
 ll\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program
 Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
 \100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShel
 l\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Prog
 ram Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26/bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\MicroSt
 rategy;C:\Program Files (x86)\MicroStrategy\Intelligence Server;C:\Program Files
  (x86)\Common Files\MicroStrategy\JRE\170_51\Win32\bin\client;

D:\Backup\Script de backup>set data=08/06/2015
D:\Backup\Script de backup>set CURRDATE=08-06-2015
D:\Backup\Script de backup>set dia=08/0
D:\Backup\Script de backup>set horario=10:34:00,10
D:\Backup\Script de backup>set CURRTIME=10:34:00,10
D:\Backup\Script de backup>set hora=10
D:\Backup\Script de backup>rar a F:\Teste Teste\Databases_08-06-2015_10.rar F:\B
 KP_Teste\My_Box_Files\Databases

RAR 4.01   Copyright (c) 1993-2011 Alexander Roshal   28 May 2011
 Shareware version         Type RAR -? for help

Evaluation copy. Please register.

Cannot open Teste\Databases_08-06-2015_10.rar
 O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado.
 Creating archive F:\Teste.rar

Adding    F:\BKP_Teste\My_Box_Files\Databases\VETORHPROD\Texto.txt    OK
 Adding    F:\BKP_Teste\My_Box_Files\Databases\VETORHPROD              OK
 Adding    F:\BKP_Teste\My_Box_Files\Databases                         OK
 Done

D:\Backup\Script de backup>pause



Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .
```

Desde já agradeço.

Daniel.

Comment: Tentou colocar o caminho entre aspas duplas? `rar a "F:\Teste Teste\Databases_%CURRDATE%_%HORA%.rar" D:\Backup\Backup_SQL\Databases`

Comment: Dessa forma eu não havia tentado ainda, mas consegui resolver desta colocando aspas dupla entre os espaços. Ficou assim: rar a F:\Teste" "Teste\Databases_%CURRDATE%_%HORA%.rar D:\Backup\Backup_SQL\Databases. 

Obrigado pela ajuda Eduardo Silva